# SQL Server Complex Case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, case, case-when

i cant find a way to do a Case for something similar to this example. I invoke his knowledge!
I received novelty every month, with letters from A to E, i need to write 0 in the bigger letter present for each customer. So if i received just B, then B=0, if i received A and B then A=1 and B=0, if i received A,B,C then A=1,B=1 and C=0, if i received A and C then A=1 and C=0,its group by Customer.

```
Customer Codes
111      A    
111      B    
111      C    
222      A        
222      B    
333      A
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say...  Can you please show some sample results?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Was "this example" meant to be a link to somewhere else? If so, you've forgotten to include it. Please [edit] your question to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In the below SQl you're doing some row number functions and then ordering by the highest row number. After that you do another row number function by the highest row_number it gets in the cte.

With myCte
as
(
Select Customer,Code,Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer Order By Code) rn
from myTable

)
select Customer,Code,
Case when rn2 = 1 then 0
else 1
end as myArbitraryNumber
 from
(
select Customer, Code, rn, Row_Number() OVER (Partition by Customer,rn Order by rn DESC) rn2 
from myCte
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to my question. i added desc to code, because i need max value in zero. and declared the last temp table with alias.  Thanks!. This is the final example:   With myCte
as
(
Select Customer,Code,Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer Order By Code desc) rn
from #myTable

)
select Customer,Code,
Case when rn=1 then 0
else 1
end as myArbitraryNumber
 from
(
select Customer, Code, rn, Row_Number() OVER (Partition by Customer,rn Order by rn DESC) rn2 
from myCte
)
as t